# Create "Service with Lines" in AnyLogic based on a parameter

Tags: anylogic

I am a beginner user of AnyLogic.
I need to simulate a train station and it would be important to create as many ticket gates (service with lines) as the user wants. Is it possible to create a parameter and create the services based on this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it is a bit un-intuitive.
Define your "Service with lines" to have many services (more than you need), as below:
[image]

Now, loop through all and set them suspended (I do it just for the first here):

```
services.getServices().get(0).setSuspended(true);
```

Now your parameter can turn them on dynamically by using setSuspended(false) for as many as you like.

hope that helps